# Find and replace text in all stored procedures (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, replace, find

I have been asked to make changes in all the stored procedure in a SQL Server database to replace `CONVERT(varchar(` with `RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(` and close with `)`.

For example - find this code:

```
CONVERT(varchar(5), col$1) + '~' + CONVERT(varchar(8), col$2) + '~AD~'
```

and replace it with:

```
RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(5), col$1)) + '~' + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(8), col$2)) + '~AD~'
```

The find code is different in other stored procedure e.g.

```
convert(varchar(10), @date_ALTERd, 103)
```

but `CONVERT(varchar(` will be same in each find code.

There are 147 stored procedures and it is quite difficult to do one by one...

Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: IMO just use find and replace function in almost every text editor and manual replace those one by one, this is not difficult, only time consuming but at least you can check will those replace break your procedure...

Comment: I can find & replace first part "CONVERT(varchar("  to "rtrim(CONVERT(varchar(" which straight forward in SQL SSMS or Notepad++ Which I have done it BUT  adding close ')' for each replacement of "rtrim(" is not straight forward unless prepare to do manually 147 SProcs. So main help needed how add close ")" either in SSMS or Notepad++?

Comment: So why don't you just **script out** the stored procedures into text files, then do the search & replace in those text files, and recreate those stored procedures that have actually been updated in the database?

Comment: That's what I did. Are you suggesting manual replace of close ")"  ? for which I am looking for help.

Comment: Yes - that is what people are suggesting. You've already spent hours trying to automate this. Trying to add the closing parenthesis is a very complex issue for which there is no built-in support in tsql. Seriously - how many instances do you need to change? And if you need to change so many, that suggests a very different problem. Have you ignored the use of CAST? Is there a test plan? How do you intend to validate and release these changes? Are there no developers or coworkers that can contribute to this tedious and simple (but easy to mess-up) task?

Answer (score 0):

notepad++ and regex for the rescue :
extract your procedure into plain text and put it in notepad++ then replace with some regex.

find:

```
(?i)CONVERT\(.*?\).*?\)(?-i)
```

replace:

```
RTRIM\($0\)
```

and here is the example result:

```
convert(varchar(5), col$1) + '~' + CONVERT(varchar(8), col$2) + '~AD~'
```

after replace:

```
RTRIM(convert(varchar(5), col$1)) + '~' + RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(8), col$2)) + '~AD~'
```

if every string start with `CONVERT(` and end with `)` this regex expression should work but be careful and check each one IMO. those should also take care of case sensitive and multiple match in one line.
if the string have more then two pairs of parentheses with in `convert(...)` then this will still fail, in that case it will be better just manual adjust.
here is [regex-101](https://regex101.com/r/iXhexB/2).

Comment: Thanks... results should be "RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(5), col$1))" a single bracket after 'CONVERT'. I am very much new for regex.

Comment: oh shoot I input one extra `(`, this should be correct now but I think this will fail if there is two `convert(...)` in same line, I'll try to come up with a solution with that.

Comment: Great... Peter,  waiting for solution for 2 convert(...) , Thanks. what about this one I just come cross "convert(varchar(30), stc.STC_DESCRIPTION)". above solution failed for this pattern.

Comment: Another one come cross "rtrim(convert(varchar(30), dbo.STREET_TYPE_CODES_STC.STC_DESCRIPTION) + char(13) + isnull(dbo.ADDRESS_AD.AD_CITY, isnull(dbo.ADDRESS_AD.AD_COUNTRY, dbo.ADDRESS_AD.AD_SUBURB))), 
               'Caravan'

Comment: edit with solution of case insensitive and multiple match problem.

Comment: That's works fine but with all kind of CONVERT  code... should only be works with "CONVERT(varchar"    but it is finding code such as "CONVERT(int, substring(@Entity_SeqNo, 1, (@DotPos - 1)))"